# Особенности работы с MySQL: Statement и PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Просьба специалистов помочь в понимании технического вопроса при работе с MySQL.

Есть таблица `items`. В качестве `primary key` выступает `id`. При добавлении новой записи `id` автоинкрементируется на `1`.

У нас есть `preparedStatement`, который записывает какую-то информацию.

После записи в таблицу, нам нужно получить последний добавленный `id`. Для этого используем `statement` и следующий запрос:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

*Внимание вопрос*: Почему это всегда работает корректно, даже без `synchronized` блока?

Comment: одно соединение Mysql в принципе не может одновременно использоваться несколькими потоками. так что посмотрите в сторону того как вы эти соединения создаете. наверняка для каждого потока открывается отдельное соединение. А last_insert_id это свойство соединения.

Comment: @Mike Ах вон откуда ноги растут. Выходит что last_insert_id работает с последним id, добавленным при помощи этого же connection'а?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: @Donatello знаю что можно возвращать вставленный `id` без доп запроса прямо из `preparedStatement`

Comment: @Donatello https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc

Comment: @Tsyklop отличная альтернатива, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Mike спасибо вам!